# Optimizing a factorial function in python

Tags: python, function, optimization, factorial

So i have achieved this function with **unpacking parameter(*x)**, but i want to make it display the result **not** return it , and i want a good **optimization** meaning i still need it to be a **two lines** function

```
1.def fac(*x):
    2.return (fac(list(x)[0], list(x)[1] - 1)*list(x)[1]) if list(x)[1] > 0 else 1//here i need the one line to print the factorial
```

i tried achieving this by implementing lambda but i didn't know how to pass the *x parameter

Comment: If the current answer solves your question then accept it with the tick mark below the voting arrows, you can change the accepted answer as many times as you wish if a better one comes along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your factorial lambda is correct. I take it that you would like to calculate the factorials for a list say [1, 2, 3] and output the results, this is how you can achieve this.

```
fact = lambda x: x*fact(x-1) if x > 0 else 1
print(*[fact(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]])
```

Which will output: 1, 2, 6

Another option, **if you have python 3.8** is to use a list comprehension with the new walrus operator (:=), this is a bit more tricky but will calculate and output all factorials up to n inclusive whilst still fitting in your required two lines.

```
fac, n = 1, 5
print(*[fac for i in range(1, n+1) if (fac := fac*i)])
```

Which will output: 1, 2, 6, 24, 120

Comment: thank you but how about the first solution (with def(*x) isn't there a way to inject a print on the second line without it being called everytime the recursif function is called !

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do that in only two lines using def. Since the function is recursive any print statement inside the function will run once the function is called again. You would have to return the result from the function and print it. Why must you write this program in only two lines?

Comment: I have edited my original answer to include a solution which works in python 3.8+ as another way to solve this problem in 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The optimized factorial number is display by the function that i have created below.

```
def fact(n):
    list_fact = []
    if n > 1 and n not in list_fact:
        list_fact.extend(list(range(1, n + 1)))
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, list_fact)
print(fact(9000))  # it will display output within microseconds.
```

**Note:**
while iteration i saved all previous values into a list, so that computation of each value is not going to happen each time.